# search(String target) method in a BinarySearchTree

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm coding a dictionary system. This system should be run like this;

1. User enters a word that s/he wants to learn the definition.
2. The words and the definitions are storing in a linked list
3. while searching I should use a binary search tree
4. bst is comparing the words
5. search(String target) method should return the word+definition

---

Problems:

- I've printed the linked list in a binary search tree but the method search() is couldn't return the word+definition? Where did I do a mistake?

---

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

private String data;
private BinarySearchTree left;
private BinarySearchTree right;

public BinarySearchTree() {
    // I've deleted the getters/setters
public void addNode(String data) {
    if (this.data == null) {
        this.data = data;
    } else {
        if (this.data.compareTo(data)> 0) {
            if (this.left != null) {
                this.left.addNode(data);
            } else {
                this.left = new BinarySearchTree(data);
            }

        } else {
            if (this.right != null) {
                this.right.addNode(data);
            } else {
                this.right = new BinarySearchTree(data);
            } 
        }
    }
}
public boolean search(BinarySearchTree t,String key) {
    if (t.data.equals(key)) return true;

    if (t.left != null && search(t.left,key)) return true;

    if (t.right != null && search(t.right,key)) return true;

    return false;
}
}

public class Vocab {
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    
    LinkedList<String> ll 
        = new LinkedList<>(); 
    Word word = new Word("Engineer", "Mühendis");
    Word word2 = new Word("School", " Okul");
    Word word3 = new Word("Pencil", "Kalem");
    Word word4 = new Word("Window", "Pencere");
  
    ll.add(word.toString());
    ll.add(word2.toString());
    ll.add(word3.toString());
    ll.add(word4.toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < ll.size(); i++) { 

        System.out.println(ll.get(i)); 
    } 

    BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
    // Using the for each loop 
    for (String str : ll) {         
        bst.addNode(str);
    }

    System.out.println("search: " );
    //here I want to return search() method and get the word+definition
    
}
```

}

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What is the `Word` class?